# How to add two Integer variables in MIPS

Tags: variables, mips, addition

I'm trying to Prompt the user to input two numbers, store them in Variables A and B, and then add the variables and save the sum to variable S. I know I can do this by saving the values directly to the registers, but I need to know how to do it using the variables themselves.

Here's my code

```
.data
prompt1: .asciiz "Enter an Integer A: /n"
prompt2: .asciiz "Enter another Integer B: /n"
response: .asciiz "The sum of A and B (A + B) is: "
A: .word 
B: .word
S: .word
.text

#Prompt for input
li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt1 
syscall

#receive input
li $v0, 5
syscall

#Store input to A
sw $v0, A
syscall

#Prompt for second input
li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt2 
syscall

#receive input
li $v0, 5
syscall

#Store input to B
sw $v0, B
syscall

#Add A and B and store to register t0
add $s0, A, B
syscall

#Store total to variable S
move S, $t0
syscall

#Display response
li $v0, 4
la $a0, response
syscall

li $v0, 1
move $a0, S
syscall
```

Comment: You can't. The ADD instruction adds two registers together. Also I'm sure you have a lot of syscalls that shouldn't be there

Comment: Yeah, `syscall` is not something you add after every instruction. It _is_ an instruction, with a specific purpose (to perform a system call, such as console I/O, dynamic memory allocation, etc).

Answer (score -1):

This is how you should write your code for your desired output :

```
    .data
    msg1: .asciiz "Enter the first number: "
    msg2: .asciiz "\nEnter the second number: "
    result: .asciiz "\nThe result of addition is: "

    .text
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,msg1
    syscall

    li $v0,5
    syscall
    move $t1,$v0

    li $v0,4
    la $a0,msg2
    syscall

    li $v0,5
    syscall
    move $t2,$v0

    Add $t3,$t1,$t2

    li $v0,4
    la $a0,msg3
    syscall

    li $v0,1
    move $a0,$t3
    syscall

    li $v0,10
    syscall
```